# Why are errors to insert a data after end of vector in c++

Tags: c++, vector, insert

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
string** DataStorage;

string line;
vector<vector<string>> extractingData(200, vector<string>(10));
vector<vector<string>> extractingData2(200, vector<string>(10));

string pathExtract;
string pathStorage;

ofstream storageFile;
ifstream storageFileRead;
fstream extractingFile;
fstream extractingFile2;


void ReadData(fstream& extractingFile, vector<vector<string>> extractingData, string pathExtract)
{
    extractingFile.open(pathExtract, ios::in | ios::out | std::ios_base::app);

    int i = 0;
    int index;
    if (extractingFile.is_open())
    {
        while (getline(extractingFile, line))
        {
            istringstream iss(line);
            int j = 0;
            while (!iss.eof()){
                iss >> extractingData[i][j];
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }

        extractingFile.close();
    }
}


int main() {
    pathExtract = "sample.txt";
    pathStorage = "mergedData.txt";
    ReadData(extractingFile, extractingData, pathStorage);
    ReadData(extractingFile2, extractingData2, pathExtract);
    mergeData(extractingData, extractingData2, pathStorage);

}


void mergeData(vector<vector<string>> extractingData, vector<vector<string>> extractingData2, string pathStorage){

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (i<extractingData.size())
    {
        while (extractingData[i][0] != extractingData2[j][0])
        {
            j++;
        }
        if (extractingData[i][0] == extractingData2[j][0])
        {
            //extractingData[i].insert
            extractingData[i].insert(extractingData[i].end(), extractingData2[j].pop_back()); // here is error
        }   
        i++;
    }

//  storageFileRead.open(pathStorage, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
    storageFileRead.open(pathStorage);
    i = 0;
    if (storageFileRead.is_open())
    {
        ofstream outFile(pathStorage);
        while (getline(storageFileRead, line)){

            std::vector<int>::const_iterator col;   
            for (col = extractingData[i].begin(); col !=extractingData[i].end(); ++col) { // here is errors, too
                outFile << *col;
                }
            outFile << endl;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a dataset like below in a text file named mergedData.txt

```
country OD DM              
Croatia 36 15
Spain 35 26
Belgium 32 38
USA 25 57
France 24 29
Estonia 24 19
```

and also new dataset is given in text file named sample.txt.

```
country VT
Estonia 21%
Belgium 26%
Croatia 6%
France 29%
Spain 13%
USA 42%
```

i want to add some new variable named VT(Volunteering Time) in the end of each lines like this.

```
country OD DM VT             
Croatia 36 15 6
Spain 35 26 13
Belgium 32 38 26
USA 25 57 42
France 24 29 29
Estonia 24 19 21
```

but there are some errors. i'll glad of any helps.

Comment: Also unless you can have multiple entries per country I would absolutely be using a `map<string vector<string>>` for this.

Comment: If you want to insert at end (after the last element) you should use `std::vector::push_back` method

Comment: i see. programming is really hard challenge for me.

Comment: @user3598732 It's not a challenge. It's fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
extractingData[i].insert(extractingData[i].end(), extractingData2[j].pop_back()); // here is error
```

`std::vector<>::pop_back` does not return a value. It just removes the element.  Get the value first, then call `pop_back`.

```
auto back = std::move(extractingData2[j].back());
extractingData2[j].pop_back();
extractingData[i].push_back(std::move(back));
```